# How can I connect Access Database with Netbeans on Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos, ms-access, netbeans

I got a access database, and I'm programming in Java.
What can i use to connect my netbeans with my database on localhost?

Only found this code(it uses local db file) for Windows:

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver " +
        "(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Database\\Northwind 2007.accdb";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+cE.toString());
}
```

Maybe someone know how to modify it for mac environment?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver available to download. Include all the jar files in the libraries of the project and you should be able to make a connection to your access database without having Access installed. UCanAccess works best with NetBeans.

Comment: For detailed setup instructions see [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

In [Access Database Manipulation via JDBC](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2) is explained step by step.

Comment: String filename = "d:/java/mdbTEST.mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
How can I do this in OS X ? And I have .accdb file not .mdb, there is defference?